# How to use classic loadbalancer with ec2 instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Working on classic loadbalancer for the first time. I created a classic loadbalancer and registered to ec2 instance. Web page loads when i enter ec2 ipaddress. But when i enter loadbalancer dns name, it shows only nginx config success page. What else is to be done to make loadbalancer redirect to ec2 instance?

Comment: The nginx page must be coming from your Amazon EC2 instance because the Load Balancer does not create content.

Comment: Thank you! I changed /etc/nginx/sites-available/default  and it started working. As u said it was coming from ec2 instance but ec2 instance was accessing gunicorn, but loadbalancer was reading default. So i made changes accordingly :).